# O que é view-port?

Tags: aplicação-web, terminologia

Nesta [minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272194/como-manter-o-tamanho-da-div-independente-do-tamanho-do-texto) o usuário [Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3635/guilherme-nascimento) mencionou um termo chamado **view-port** na sua reposta em relação a uma div e o CSS dela, este termo é desconhecido para mim e me gerou algumas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é view-port?
2. Qual a relação que o view-port tem com a minha aplicação Web?
3. Só existe o view-port ou há outra coisa similar a ele?

Comment: É a área do browser onde o seu site ou aplicação aparece. O CSS oferece unidades de medida proporcionais ao tamanho dessa área.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51244/media-query-não-funciona-em-site-não-responsivo/51248#51248

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## O que é *viewport*?

Em computação gráfica, a *viewport* é a porção de área visível de um plano.

## Qual a relação que a *viewport* tem com a minha aplicação web?

Quando falamos em web responsiva, a *viewport* é a área visível pelo usuário de uma página web. O conteúdo que não está visível, só pode ser visto com um *scroll*, por exemplo.

[image]

Perceba que a *viewport* varia de dispositivo para dispositivo, por exemplo em computadores, tablets e celulares. Ele também varia, por exemplo, quando o usuário redimensiona o tamanho do seu navegador em seu sistema operacional.

O HTML5 introduziu a [*metatag<sup>inglês</sup>*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) `name="viewport"`, que deixa o desenvolvedor ter controle na área visível do navegador.

Existem também medidas relativas no CSS que tem o tamanho da *viewport* como base. Veja:

- `vw`: relativo a 1% da largura da *viewport*
- `vh`: relativo a 1% da altura da *viewport*
- `vmin`: relativo a 1% da dimensão mais baixa da *viewport*
- `vmax`: relativo a 1% da dimensão mais alta da *viewport*

Isso facilita muito o desenvolvimento de páginas 100% responsivas.

## Só existe a *viewport* ou há outra coisa similar a ela?

Na web existem duas *viewports*. A que é visível, é chamada de **visual viewport**. Ela geralmente é menor que a **layout viewport**, que é o conteúdo inteiro. Quando um usuário dá *zoom* na página com seu celular, por exemplo, a **layout viewport** continua a mesma, quem muda (no caso diminui) é a **visual viewport**. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui<sup>inglês</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/viewport).